# BoostPython Default parameter lost

Tags: python, c++, boost

Ok. My game engine is writen in C++ and uses Boost::Python to interpret python for scripting. You can manually create scenes and objects from python. I know that you use BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS when wrapping default parameters from member function. For example Translate function uses 3D vector and transform space which by default is TS_WORLD. This works fine. Problem starts when a function returns object and needs return_value_policy definition. For example. Scene class has function CreateCamera(std::string name = ""), which if parameter is set will name the camera otherwise it will generate name itself. Function returns pointer of Camera class. And here is my Python code:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(CreateCamera_Overload, Scene::CreateCamera, 0, 1);
de
class_< ...
.def("CreateCamera", &Scene::CreateCamera, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>(), CreateCamera_Overload());
```

This compiles without problem. But when called from python:

```
camera = Scene.CreateCamera()
```

...I get following error:

Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in Scene.CreateArea(Scene)
did not match C++ signature:
     CreateCamera(class Scene {lvalue}, class std::basic_string, class std::allocator>)

It somehow misses default argument. The function doesnt throw error if I pass name for the camera of pass "". If I change function to void and skip return_value_policy (which obviously is not right) then it works without error. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: I don't know, but you can work around it by simply writing a second version of the function which really takes one argument.